# Android: EditText cannot gain focus after being re-enabled

Tags: android, focus, android-widget, android-edittext

I have a TabHost with three tabs. The first tab's content is the Intent of a custom activity who's contentview is a relative layout containing two EditTexts and two CheckBoxes (and a button).

Each checkbox, when checked, enables/disables one EditText and the other checkbox. and I went about that like this:

```
chkPolaziste.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                entryPolaziste.setFocusable(false);
                entryPolaziste.setEnabled(false);
                chkOdrediste.setFocusable(false);
                chkOdrediste.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                entryPolaziste.setEnabled(true);
                entryPolaziste.setFocusable(true);
                chkOdrediste.setEnabled(true);
                chkOdrediste.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

And that works. When one checkbox is checked, it disables the other checkbox and his EditText, and when I uncheck it, EditText and the other checkbox are enabled. But, after it's enabled, I can't type anything into the EditText. It just flicks for a moment when I 
click on it, and switches focus to another view. It looks to me as though the control is not fully enabled.

I've also tried to force the focus on the re-enabled EditText with requestFocus(), and tried to setFocusableInTouchMode(), but neither had worked.

I don't have an android device, so I only test this in the emulator (Min SDK is 1.6).

Comment: Important note: This behaviour is manifested only for touch (when i click the EditText, but it works normally with the track ball (that's why I've tried setFocusableInTouchMode method).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Workaround:

Use `setFocusableInTouchMode` and `setFocusable`, both of them.

Comment: Thanks - this was a huge help! (Any ideas on why this is necessary?)

Comment: Wow, this saved me from marathon debugging

Comment: works just fine with setFocusableInTouchMode(true) as well, thanks

Comment: but is it selectable with .setTextIsSelectable(true) statement? I found the text however is not selectable (to copy or cut). How to make it selectable?